# relation between R-squared and sample size

Tags: regression, least-squares, sample-size, r-squared

Here is the question:

> Suppose $X, Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables. And take the regression of $Y$ against $X.$ What is the relationship between $R^2$ and sample size approximately?

First I am not sure if "independent" is a typo in the original question. In ordinary least squares (OLS), there is no specific relation between $R^2$ and sample size.

Here R2 is defined as:
$$R2 = 1 - \dfrac{RSS}{TSS}.$$
$$RSS = \sum(y_i-\hat{y})^2,\ TSS = \sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2.$$
And in the simple linear regress with interception, R2 is exactly correlation between X and Y.

Comment: Simulate two independent standard normal distributions and calculate the correlation. Is it equal to zero? What happens if you increase the sample size by a factor of ten?

Comment: @Dave I am wrong and updated. Duplicate samples will not change R2.

Comment: Simulate `cor(rnorm(5,), rnorm(5))^2` in R. Now do it for $10$, then $20$, then $50$, then $100$.

Comment: It seems like you’re using the same definition of $R^2$ that I use in my answer.

Comment: In OLS there is a mathematically predictable relationship between the *expected value* of $R^2$ and sample size.  Moreover, given a sample size you can express the distribution of $R^2$ in the sample in closed form: see the [F Ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sample size increases, $R^2$ decreases toward zero.

Since the two variables are independent, they have zero correlation and, thus, zero squared correlation. With a small sample size, some bad luck might result in there being a high empirical correlation. As the sample size increase, however, the empirical correlation will tend toward the true value of zero, hence the squared correlation tending toward zero.

Let’s look at it in a simulation.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
Ns <- rep(seq(3, 550, 1), 4) 
r2 <- rep(Ns)
for (i in 1:length(Ns)){
    x <- rnorm(Ns[i])
    y <- rnorm(Ns[i])
    r2[i] <- (cor(x, y))^2
}
d <- data.frame(
    sample_size = Ns,
    r2 = r2
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = sample_size, y = r2)) +
    geom_point()
    xlab(“Sample Size”) +
    ylab(“R^2”)
```

[image: Squared correlation by sample size]

Comment: why R2 is same as correlation here? I know under OLS assumption, R2 is exactly the correlation between X and Y (with interception).

Comment: @user6703592 In simple linear regression (with an intercept), there are a bunch of equivalent definitions of $R^2$, and I picked the one that is easiest to calculate. If you have an equation you prefer, please do post it. Perhaps even try using it in the simulation to see that you get the same trend. // $R^2$ is not the same as correlation here. $R^2$ is the squared correlation, as my code calculates.

Comment: pls see my update. I understand as here R2 is close to the square of correlation but not exactly same. And finally tends to zero?

Comment: I can understand it will tend to zero, but I cannot understand under my definition, why it is the empirical correlation between X and Y. Since the cross term is not necessary zero.

Comment: Do you mean why the $1-RSS/TSS$ definition equals the squared correlation?

Comment: yes, simple linear regression of OLS is true,  but not true here

Comment: You could be more quantitative about this: $R^2$ is almost surely *nonzero* and you can figure out the rate, as a function of sample size, that it approaches zero.  If you would like a strong hint about the relationship, redraw your plot with `scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()` added and add a smooth.

Comment: @user6703592 How do you figure it is not true here? What regression are you calculating if not OLS linear regression?

Comment: sorry I mean the usual simple linear regression assumption i.e. $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i,$ $x_i$ is non-random.

Comment: How do you calculate the RSS? Sure, you have a formula, but what is $\hat y$ in that formula? @user6703592

Comment: solve optimal $\beta$ match OLS. I get, actually the solution is independent on the assumption of distribution of $X,Y,$ the result of R2 is still correlation. Unless we use MLE to solve $\beta,$ the story will be different.

Comment: If you estimate the slope and intercept in a way other than OLS, you lack the usual guarantee that $(\text{corr}(y,\hat y))^2 = 1-RSS/TSS$, so if a maximum likelihood estimate gives a different estimated parameter vector, you do not need to have the above equality, and you might even wind up with $R^2=1-RSS/TSS<0$.